# WordPress with data storage and retrieval

Tags: wordpress

I am an experienced Asp.NET developer. However, I am new to WordPress development. Since Asp.NET development can take time and money, I was probing other options. It appears WordPress has reduced development time with nice free themes. I am planning to create a news website. I saw several videos on YouTube describing how easy it is to create a fully functional WordPress website with a few drag and drops. However they never mention the following:

1. Whatever content we create as part of the website, will it be stored somewhere, say in a database?
2. When new contents are added, can the old contents be viewed through a link or they are gone?
3. What database is used to store WordPress data?

If you can point me to a course which addresses these issues - even if it's a paid course - please let me know.

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO, since you are asking for off-site resources. However, to answer: 1. Yes, WP is PHP based and data is stored in a DB using MySQL. 2. Not sure what this means, but if you edit/update content, there is a revision history that's stored in the DB. 3. MySQL or potentially MariaDB